# How match file extension in url that can end with querystring?

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I want to match the file extension in all of the following URLs **only** up to the question mark. So URL #4 would match the pdf in "file.pdf" but not "exe" in "otherfile.exe".

```
http://www.someplace.com/directory/file.pdf
http://www.someplace.com/directory/file.pdf?otherstuff=true
http://www.someplace.com/directory/file.pdf?other=true&more=false
http://www.someplace.com/directory/file.pdf?other=true&more=false&value=otherfile.exe
```

How do I do this?

I tried this, but it's not working:

```
([^\.]+)(\?|[^\?]$)+
```

Comment: Have you tried using PHP's `parse_url()`?

Comment: I'm not sure if you want to just know if there is a match or if you want the host and path from the string. Please specify.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This would be the version I would  use

```
/\w+\.[A-Za-z]{3,4}(?=\?|$)/
```

Here is a working version:

http://regex101.com/r/sY2fR0/1

Using look ahead with either ? Or end of the string `(?=\?|$)` you then can match what is behind it.

```
$re = "/\\w+\\.[A-Za-z]{3,4}(?=\\?|$)/"; 
$str = "http://www.someplace.com/directory/file.pdf?other=true&more=false&value=otherfile.exe\n\n"; 

preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it matches from too early of a "." in this case: `http://www.com.com/something/sampson.masterplan.pdf?sdf` it will match "masterplan.pdf" Is there a way to fix that? (also, I added `0-9` so it can match mp3)

Comment: I changed it slightly to: `/\w+\.([A-Za-z0-9]{3,4})(?=\?|$)/`

Answer (score 0):

For a match try this case insensitive function:

```
function matchURLs($desiredURL, $compareURL){
  $url = parse_url($compareURL);
  if(preg_match('/^'$url['scheme'].'://'.$url['host'].$url['path'].'$/i', $desiredURL)){
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
matchURLs('http://www.someplace.com/directory/file.pdf', 'http://www.someplace.com/directory/file.exe'); // false
matchURLs('http://www.someplace.com/directory/file.pdf', 'http://www.someplace.com/directory/file.pdf?value=file.exe'); // true
```

To just get the before the `?`:

```
function URL_before_query($url){
  $u = parse_url($url);
  return $u['scheme'].'://'.$u['host'].$u['path'];
}
echo URL_before_query('http://www.someplace.com/directory/file.pdf?other=true&more=false&value=otherfile.exe'); // http://www.someplace.com/directory/file.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
$str = '
http://www.someplace.com/directory/file1.pdf
http://www.someplace.com/directory/file2.pdf?otherstuff=true 
http://www.someplace.com/directory/file3.pdf?other=true&more=false 
http://www.someplace.com/directory/file4.pdf?other=true&more=false&value=otherfile.exe
';
$regex= '~.*/\K[^?\n]+~';

preg_match_all($regex, $str, $out, PREG_SET_ORDER);
print_r($out);
?>
```

**Output**

```
Array ( 
   [0] => Array ( 
                 [0] => file1.pdf 
                ) 
   [1] => Array ( 
                 [0] => file2.pdf 
                ) 
   [2] => Array ( 
                 [0] => file3.pdf 
                ) 
   [3] => Array ( 
                 [0] => file4.pdf 
                 ) 
  )
```